# How to make 2D character do one step of 32 pixels when pressing a button once in Godot's 4 GDScript?

Tags: game-physics, game-development, godot, gdscript, godot4

I wrote a script where I move my 2D character after once pressing a button one step. But it moves only 1 pixels instead of 32 and also jumps up for 1 pixel.

There is a function that measures the distance the character has walked and supposed to stop the character when reaching this distance. Now I am struggling to implement the logic, as this script seems correct, but the character walks only 1 pixel, but the debug says it did 32. Somehow problem expands even on velocity.y value, because character jumps only 1 pixel (roughly 1 frame). I know I am missing something but can't understand where exactly.

I am relatively new in this Godot 4 engine, please help me as I already spent days troubleshooting this issue and watching tutorials. If you see other minor issues I don't see or things that can be optimized please also let me know. If you know a good tutorial on this topic, I will appreciate the sharing.

Here is the function that do the step:

```
func step(dir, delta):
    #if 32 or -32 pixels move character, if not stop character
    if dir != 0:
        velocity.x = dir * speed * delta #move player 32 pixels left or right
        measured_distance += abs(velocity.x) #add walked value to a measurer (and make it always positive)
        measured_distance = min(measured_distance, abs(dir)) #if measurer exceeds 32 pixels make it 32
        print ("measured_distance: ", measured_distance) #debug , always works
        #if measurer equals to 32 pixels or exceeds it
        if measured_distance >= abs(dir):
            print(measured_distance, " px passed") #debug, always works
            dir_distance = 0 #reset universal directory distance to 0
            stepping = false #announcing the end of stepping process
    else:
        stop_step()
```

Here is the full script:

```
extends CharacterBody2D

#MOVEMENT
@export var speed: int = 100
@export var step_distance: int = 32 #distance of 32 pixels
@export var jump_velocity: int = -230
var measured_distance: int = 0 #variable used to measure walked distance each step
var stepping: bool = false
var dir_distance: int = 0 #variable that inherits step_distance but changes direction to negative or positive

#PHYSICS
var gravity = ProjectSettings.get_setting("physics/2d/default_gravity")

#function called from the _physics_process one, it resets the measured_distance and announce stepping process
func start_measure ():
    stepping = true
    measured_distance = 0

#stops player movement along x value (horizontal)
func stop_step ():
    velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, 0, speed)


func step(dir, delta):
    #if 32 or -32 pixels move character, if not stop character
    if dir != 0:
        velocity.x = dir * speed * delta #move player 32 pixels left or right
        measured_distance += abs(velocity.x) #add walked value to a measurer (and make it always positive)
        measured_distance = min(measured_distance, abs(dir)) #if measurer exceeds 32 pixels make it 32
        print ("measured_distance: ", measured_distance) #debug , always works
        #if measurer equals to 32 pixels or exceeds it
        if measured_distance >= abs(dir):
            print(measured_distance, " px passed") #debug, always works
            dir_distance = 0 #reset universal directory distance to 0
            stepping = false #announcing the end of stepping process
    else:
        stop_step() 

#script starts here
func _physics_process(delta):
        #if not standing on floor add gravity
    if !is_on_floor():
        velocity.y += gravity * delta
    #if jump pressed once...
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump") and is_on_floor():
        velocity.y = jump_velocity * delta

    #if not doing any step currently allow to press left or right buttons
    if !stepping:
        if Input.is_action_just_pressed("right"):
            dir_distance = step_distance #inherit value with positive value (right)
            start_measure()
        elif Input.is_action_just_pressed("left"):
            dir_distance = -step_distance #inherit value with negative value (left)
            start_measure()

        #constantly update movement
    step(dir_distance, delta) #passes direction (32 pixels left or right) and delta value
    move_and_slide()
```

[Here is how it looks in the game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1Xf4.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure, but I think move_and_slide already adds delta to the velocity, so your actually moved distance differs from the measured_distance.

I am not 100% sure, but I thought move_and_slide already applies delta, which would explain, why you are just moving 1 pixel. But removing delta from velocity.x did not do it, so I have another solution for you. Instead of adding a distance, you are not sure of, you could save the start position, when you are starting to move and check on each iteration, if the player moved 32 px to the left or right.
That way you can actually hard set the position of the player, when he reached the 32 px.

your step part would look like this:

```
func step(dir, delta):
#if 32 or -32 pixels move character, if not stop character
if dir != 0:
    velocity.x = dir * speed * delta #move player 32 pixels left or right
    
    if abs(position.x - start_pos.x) >= abs(dir):
        print(measured_distance, " px passed") #debug, always works
        dir_distance = 0 #reset universal directory distance to 0
        stepping = false #announcing the end of stepping process
        position.x = start_pos.x + dir #hard set the position to start+32
        velocity.x = 0 #destination reached, so no need to move further
else:
    stop_step()
```

start_pos will be set in the pysics_process part which checks for stepping:

```
if !stepping:
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("right"):
        start_pos = position
        dir_distance = step_distance #inherit value with positive value (right)
        start_measure()
    elif Input.is_action_just_pressed("left"):
        start_pos = position
        dir_distance = -step_distance #inherit value with negative value (left)
        start_measure()
```

Note: you should check if move_and_slide collided with something and end the movement, if so. Otherwise manupulating the position directy could lead to unwanted behaviour (getting stuck in a wall for example).

Edit: Including my whole script, because it does not seem to work for Mimo

```
extends CharacterBody2D

#MOVEMENT
@export var speed: int = 100
@export var step_distance: int = 32 #distance of 32 pixels
@export var jump_velocity: int = -230
var measured_distance: int = 0 #variable used to measure walked distance each step
var stepping: bool = false
var dir_distance: int = 0 #variable that inherits step_distance but changes direction to negative or positive

#PHYSICS
var gravity = ProjectSettings.get_setting("physics/2d/default_gravity")

#function called from the _physics_process one, it resets the measured_distance and announce stepping process
func start_measure ():
    stepping = true
    measured_distance = 0

#stops player movement along x value (horizontal)
func stop_step ():
    velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, 0, speed)

var start_pos

func step(dir, delta):
    #if 32 or -32 pixels move character, if not stop character
    if dir != 0:
        velocity.x = dir * speed * delta #move player 32 pixels left or right
        
        if abs(position.x - start_pos.x) >= abs(dir):
            print(measured_distance, " px passed") #debug, always works
            dir_distance = 0 #reset universal directory distance to 0
            stepping = false #announcing the end of stepping process
            position.x = start_pos.x + dir
            velocity.x = 0
    else:
        stop_step() 

#script starts here
func _physics_process(delta):
        #if not standing on floor add gravity
    if !is_on_floor():
        velocity.y += gravity * delta
    #if jump pressed once...
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump") and is_on_floor():
        velocity.y = jump_velocity * delta

    #if not doing any step currently allow to press left or right buttons
    if !stepping:
        if Input.is_action_just_pressed("right"):
            start_pos = position
            dir_distance = step_distance #inherit value with positive value (right)
            start_measure()
        elif Input.is_action_just_pressed("left"):
            start_pos = position
            dir_distance = -step_distance #inherit value with negative value (left)
            start_measure()

        #constantly update movement
    step(dir_distance, delta) #passes direction (32 pixels left or right) and delta value
    if not velocity == Vector2.ZERO:
        print(velocity)
    move_and_slide()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and trying to help my problem, Bugfish!

Unfortunately this didn't help. Now the character doesn't move at all. Just stands on one position. I also assume start_pos was Vector2 type of variable. I used for this purpose measured_distance variable of type int but played it a bit different. I'd still keep trying to solve this with other methods, but it is now so frustrating that I am thikning of giving up the idea of moving 32 pixels only and bring back the standard movement system that worked.

Comment: BTW, I also used move_toward function that worked well, but what made me reconsider using it is problems with collision. When character hit the wall the step func was actively running each frame never reaching its distance. Also move_toward didn't really worked with jumping.

Comment: Wierd. I tested it, and my Character moved exactly 32 pixel.
I edit my answer to include the whole code.

As I mentioned at the end of my answer: After moving you should check if you collided and set stepping accordingly. if you have no slopes consider using move_and_collide to check if you reached a wall

Comment: Thank you, Bugfish, it works. My old script was buggy, but I couldn't find why. I had an error with Invalid get index 'x' (on base Nil) for the start_pos var. But with your script it somehow works flawlessly. However the minor problem still occurs, the character still jumps one pixel only. Maybe you have some ideas on how to avoid this problem? It would be highly appreciated .

Comment: I am also trying to upvote your answer, but I don't have this privilege yet. Sorry ;)

Comment: I am at work so I can't check it until this evening. But try removing delta from velocity.y = jump_velocity * delta

Comment: It did it. The whole time it was messed up is because of the delta. Now I will try to handle collisions, because it is the problem currently. However it is the whole different kind of question. Thank you for reaching out to my problem Bugfish. Wish you happy codding, and have a good day!